# How to make angular controller wait for DOM to load in meteor

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, meteor

Does anyone know how to make an angular controller wait for the entire DOM to load before executing an instruction using the Meteor framework?

I am trying to add a youtube iframe to a webpage using the process youtube API suggests where you create a temporary div and then set the iframe to that div in the angular controller (example here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). However, when I switch to a different page and then come back to the iframe page, the controller runs the iframe creation function before the DOM is loaded. Thus, when the iframe player is created it its set to a div that does not yet exist in the DOM.

I've googled this question and only been able to find the following solution for Blaze templates: `Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {... })`. Is there an equivalent for angular templates (html pages), or is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: I think you may need to put it in a directive

Comment: you can use resolve in route.. when resolve is solved then only your page will open